# Find min max using lagrange multiplier

Tags: matlab

Im trying to find min and max using lagrange multiplier but the function keep return unknow condition...
i want the solution to be numerical using vpa and double but those aren't working either
result:
[image: z_max]

```
clc; clear all; close all;
%define variable and z, g function
syms x y lamda;
z = 2*x^2 -2*x*y + y^3;
g = x^2 + y^2 - 4;
zg = z - lamda*g;
%%%%% find differential
dzg_x= diff(zg,x);
dzg_y = diff(zg,y);
dzg_lamda = diff(zg,lamda);
%%%solve system of 3 equations
[ax, ay, lamda] = solve(dzg_x,dzg_y,dzg_lamda,[x y lamda]);
 ax = ax(1:4);
ay = ay(1:4);
%substitude root into z and save the result into d matrix
for i = 1:length(ax)
 d = subs(z,{x,y},{ax ay});
end
z_max = max(d);
z_min = min(d);
%z_max = vpa(z_max);
%z_min = vpa(z_min);
z_max
z_min
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.